# PHP object property false evaluation with operator "=="

Tags: php, object, evaluation

Can somebody explain this? (PHP Version 7.2.18)

```
$data = new stdClass(); 
$data->status = 0;
print($data->status == "foo"); //true
print($data->status === "foo"); //false
```

Comment: The first one is converting `"foo"` to a number. This returns `0` because there are no digits, so it's equal to `$data->status`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with object properties, it would be the same with `$data = 0` and `print($data == "foo")`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Note that this has changed in PHP 8, both will return `false` there.

Comment: See [Loose comparison table](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).